# What made us to change from vegetarians to non vegetarians

Tags: genesis

As per Genesis 1:29-30, all living animals, birds and adam eve will be pure vegetarians.
Why we change from vegetarian to non vegetarian?
If it is because of we eat the fruit then why animals and birds changed.

Comment: Perhaps some interpret it as the heavenly or edenic life in which wild animals eat vegetables, lions live with lambs without killing or bloodshed.

Comment: I think it is as simple as the entrance of sin which always includes violence.  However, the Bible does not say.

Answer (score -1):

During the Flood, not only were all of the terrestrial animals destroyed, along with man, but the vegetation was largely destroyed, leaving very little that would be edible.  As the record shows, Noah tested to see how extensively the waters still covered the earth by sending birds out of the ark's window.

> <sup>8</sup>Also he sent forth a dove from him, to see if the waters
> were abated from off the face of the ground; <sup>9</sup>But the dove
> found no rest for the sole of her foot, and she returned unto him into
> the ark, for the waters were on the face of the whole earth: then he
> put forth his hand, and took her, and pulled her in unto him into the
> ark. (Genesis 8:8-9, KJV)

He later sent the dove out again, and it returned with an olive leaf.  But it did not return with olives!

It would take time for a harvest to come, even if Noah and his family planted gardens as soon as they had left the ark.  So God gave Noah and his family permission to eat the "clean" animals which had been preserved in the ark (see Genesis 9:2-4; cf. Genesis 7:2).

Yet God knew that eating flesh would shorten man's life.

> <sup>4</sup>Every moving thing that liveth shall be meat for you; even
> as the green herb have I given you all things. <sup>4</sup>But flesh
> with the life thereof, which is the blood thereof, shall ye not eat.
> <sup>5</sup>And surely your blood of your lives will I require; at the
> hand of every beast will I require it, and at the hand of man; at the
> hand of every man's brother will I require the life of man. (Genesis
> 9:3-5, KJV)

Indeed, the Biblical record shows a dramatic reduction in lifespans following the Flood after which meat-eating was first permitted.

### Conclusion

Eating meat was permitted by God after the Flood out of necessity, as food was yet too scarce to obtain until crops could be harvested.

Comment: The dove returned to the ark with an olive branch, indicating the preservation of vegetation despite the flood and that it was safe to release the animals without fear of them all eating one another. -1.

Comment: @NigelJ _"The dove returned to the ark with an olive branch,..."_ Oh, indeed.  And Adam and Eve sewed fig _branches_ together to make themselves a covering, too.

Comment: This is the answer that the question seems to imply, but it seems to read a lot between the lines rather than being based on biblical evidence.

Comment: Plants can grow pretty fast. 
"even as the green herb have I given you all things" - the herbs where not given out of necessity.
Eating meat was not a temporary permission out of necessity, but permitted from there on onward.

Comment: @RoelfMartins Given the right environment and a tropical climate, you are most certainly correct.  But the ark did not land in the tropics, and would have left Noah and his family "high and dry" (pun intended) with respect to the distance needed to travel to such a place.  Biologists understand that it can take 100 years to replace topsoil that has been lost, during which time very little will grow, usually beginning with some kinds of grass.  Humans cannot subsist on grass, but sheep, cows, etc. _can_.